# HTML Table Item Rendering outside the table

Tags: html, html-table

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YJYYYG?editors=1000

Check out how this is rendering in the codepen. The "ID" is supposed to be a  for the first row.

I'm aware this is probably a basic html error but I cannot find an answer as to why it happens.

Sorry for asking what I am sure is a repeat question. Code included below per SO requirement.

Any further feedback on my usage of HTML tables would be appreciated as well.

```
<tr>                                             
    <th style='padding:4px; font-family:Segoe UI,arial,sans-serif; text-align: left;'>id</th>
    <th style='padding:4px; font-family:Segoe UI,arial,sans-serif; text-align: left;'>title</th>
    <th style='padding:4px; font-family:Segoe UI,arial,sans-serif; text-align: left;'>author</th>
    <th style='padding:4px; font-family:Segoe UI,arial,sans-serif; text-align: left;'>price</th>
    <th style='padding:4px; font-family:Segoe UI,arial,sans-serif; text-align: left;'>qty</th>                                                                               
</tr>
```

Comment: You always need to post a [mcve] *in your question*, not part of the code with a link to an offsite resource. That said, your issue is a typo. You're missing a `'` in your table's style attribute

Comment: Always try to use external css as you see in your case there is lot of inline css which is not good. If you had written external css for this then you could have figured it out by your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you were missing a quote in the first line:

```
<table align='center' border='1px solid black' style='... width: 100%;>
```

has to be

```
<table align='center' border='1px solid black' style='... width: 100%;'>    
----------------------------------------------------------------------^
```